# jQuery mouseenter loosing focus

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am creating a magnifying zoom and need a div to follow the mouse pointer around. All this is functioning fine apart from one issue. I am using mouseenter on the main image to insert the magnified div. This magnified div is then positioned where the mouse is, the issue here is that the mouse then looses focuses on the main img and the magnified div is gone, because the mouseenter doesn't appear to carry on focusing.

```
$('.featuredProdImg').mouseenter(function() {
  for (var i = 0; i < 1; i++) {
    var img = $(this);
    //magnifying div gets added
  }
  $(img).mousemove(function() {
    //get mouse coordinates and position magnified div here
  });
});
```

I have the magnification and everything else all working fine, its just the mouseenter not remaining active when the magnified div is positioned where the mouse is.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: any chance you can reproduce it in a jsfiddle?

Comment: you can add the event to the magnifier , and calculate its position , since you know where you entered it.

Answer (score 0):

You can specify `pointer-events: none` to your magnifying DIV for it to not capture the mouse event thereby causing a mouseleave on the image.